# "i want to use same SSL certificate on multiple device(esp8266) for mqtt connection, am i able to do that"?

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, esp8266, starttls

I am new to this, but i am using AWS IOT CORE with esp8266. So, here i am connecting esp8266 to mqtt broker which is on AWS cloud and sending data to it. Which mean my esp8266 is a client which is connected to a broker AWS IOT CORE.

SO, my main question is that when i connect single esp8266 to AWS IOT CORE then i need some certificates like CA, CERTI & Private key etc.. These file's provide secure TLS connection of esp8266 with AWS MQTT IOT core. But now i want to connect 2x esp8266 with the same Mqtt Broker with same Topic but most essentially  with same TLS certificates that i generated earlier for esp8266 (1). So is it possible to use those same certificates to provide secure TLS connection to both esp8266 at the same time.

Need a answer to that in a described manner. Do help me out here.

For reference i used this project to connect my esp8266 with AWS IOT CORE through MQTT

https://electronicsinnovation.com/how-to-connect-nodemcu-esp8266-with-aws-iot-core-using-arduino-ide-mqtt/

Answer (score 1):

No, client certificates are used to uniquely identify each connecting client.

You need to use a separate certificate per device.

Comment: But i just added same certificates to both the esp8266  and they both worked pretty well. Also both of them were sending data to aws iot core at same time. It is working pretty well.

Comment: Even if it does work it completely ignores the point of using certificates for client side identification.